# Filtering columns in data table by vector of names

Tags: r, data.table

I am learning data.table and trying to filter certain columns by using a vector containing a set of column names.

```
> dt <- data.table(A=1:5, B=2:6, C=3:7)
> dt
   A B C
1: 1 2 3
2: 2 3 4
3: 3 4 5
4: 4 5 6
5: 5 6 7
> 
> list <- c("A", "B")
> dt[ ,list, with=FALSE]
   A B
1: 1 2
2: 2 3
3: 3 4
4: 4 5
5: 5 6
>
```

This works fine and filter columns.
However, the "missing" item in the list will return an error:

```
> list <- c("A", "B", "D")
> dt[ ,list, with=FALSE]
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , list, with = FALSE) : 
  column(s) not found: D
```

How can I ignore the missing column name from the list and return just existing columns from the dt data.table?

Comment: `dt[ ,intersect(names(dt),list), with=FALSE]`

Comment: `list` is a bad name for a variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dt[ ,colnames(dt) %in% list, with=FALSE]
```

Comment: @R.B: grate answer. However, still one question! I do not understand why we need  'with=FALSE'?